# Is there anything wrong with this question?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> Which of these do you think is considered the hardest programming language to master?

Is this question grammatically correct, Is there more simple ways to ask it?

Comment: Please, be aware that asking for proofreading is frowned upon here. You generally need to make your question more specific than just "is that correct?" if you don't want it to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your sentence is grammatically absolutely fine. If by a simpler way to ask that question you mean fewer words, then get rid of the word *considered*, make *programming language* plural and move it to the beginning of the sentence:

> Which of these programming languages do you think is the hardest to master?